# VBA Time limit macro

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I'm attempting to make a GUI for a school project in Excel of a basic security system. I'm trying to have the macro take the user to the alarm slide (slide 8) if the timer runs out and if the disarm boolean is false. However, as I have it now, no matter what the user is always taken to the alarm slide once the timer runs out. I'm not sure what the issue is exactly.

The ARM_DISARM is run by an action button on the disarmed slide.

```
Global Disarm As Boolean


Sub timelimit()


Disarm = False
ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.View.GotoSlide (3)

Dim time As Date
time = Now()

Dim count As Integer
count = 5

time = DateAdd("s", count, time)

Do Until time < Now()
DoEvents

    For i = 3 To 6 'slide numbers'
    ActivePresentation.Slides(i).Shapes("countdown").TextFrame.TextRange = Format((time - Now()), "hh:mm:ss")
    Next i

Loop

If Disarm = False Then
ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.View.GotoSlide (8)
End If
    
End Sub

Sub ARM_DISARM()

Disarm = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Your timelimit sub sets Disarm to false but never changes it to True, so Disarm is always going to be False when it gets to the If Disarm = False line.

Comment: @SteveRindsberg Does the ARM_DISARM sub not set Disarm to true when it's activated?

Comment: Yes, but as I mentioned, your timelimit sub sets it to false in the first line of the sub and nothing in the sub changes that later.

Comment: @SteveRindsberg I apologize this is my first time using doing something like this. How could I have it change in the sub? I thought having it as a global variable and then using another sub to change it to False would also affect it in the other sub.

Comment: Perhaps I'm being dense (it's been known to happen; just ask my wife if you don't believe me), but I don't see where you're calling ARM_DISARM from within sub Timelimit. And since Timelimit immediately sets Disarm=False and never (as far as I can tell) changes it, the If Disarm = False test will always run.